# Open-source city cartography tool (GIS software)

Tags: maps, drawing, image-editor, mapping

I am looking for a software product to run on a PC with either Windows or Linux and that is preferably free or open-source.

I need to be able to draw roads, buildings, parks (and other green areas) and bodies of water on a 2D Goole-maps-like map. The goal is to make a map of a city easily, rather, for example, create roads by drawing individual lines, aligning them, then setting colour between them and etc.

I am **not** looking for a tool that will draw over/download/save an existing map. I am not looking for software that can be used to add waypoints/pins/save places on an existing map, neither be able to draw lines and other shapes on one. I am looking for a tool to help me draw roads, buildings, etc. with ease.

Despite my thorough research that started on the March 8th, I have still not found anything that is even close to what I need. A recommendation on what to search for on Google, a name of product, or any idea at all would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what programs have you investigated that you have rejected, and perhaps the reason for rejection? It appears that your task is not truly map related, as the description implies a simple vector editor such as Inkscape.

Comment: @fred_dot_u I couldn't find any software to create maps. Yes, I could use a vector editor, but this would take x5 more time to draw a simple road and etc.

Comment: im not quite sure on this bit "Im looking for a tool to help me draw roads" in 2D - but "I am not looking for a tool that will draw lines or other shapes"....    That counters itself? If you want to draw a road, you will be drawing a line, then styling it to look like a road? So maybe you need to clarify this part

Answer (score 2):

You are looking for GIS software, and although it is a broad subject I will give you some two options that you can research to see if one suits your needs.

1. [Arcgis Online](https://www.arcgis.com/home/index.html) Use it to make maps, look at data, share, and collaborate.  Do the free 21 day trial to see advanced features and editing tools.
2. [OpenStreetMap](https://www.openstreetmap.org/about) crowd sourced digitization of maps to possibly eliminate some legwork

Comment: Thank you very much for the information. Just by googling "GIS Software" I can now find exactly what I need! I also checked the links you have provided. The first one's website is kind of broken/outdated and at some point in time starts showing 404s everywhere. For the second one I could only find their tool to draw over existing map layers (they call it uMap or something like that).

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Geographic information system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_information_system).

The Java editor of OpenStreetMap [JOSM](https://josm.openstreetmap.de/) enables you to edit not only the map of OpenStreetMap, but also your personal (copied or invented) local map. You can invent your imaginary city in an empty map.

You can [render your personal map in the OSM format offline](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Rendering).
**Examples for fictional maps with OSM technology** can be found [in the osm wiki](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/User:Ika-chan!/Fantasy_maps_with_OSM_software), [and on this osm wiki page](https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/4496/how-to-create-fantasyimaginary-maps-with-openstreetmap) for a start.

You should also have a look at [GRASS](https://grass.osgeo.org/).

Comment: These are all for maps based on the real world. The tool I am looking for would preferably allow me to draw buildings and roads that do not exist on land that is not real either. What I am trying to achieve is a Google-maps-like map of an imaginary city

Comment: @user10398534 You can really invent your city locally. I have updated my answer.